# How to create a class that shows a plot for an argumment (Confusion matrix)

Tags: python, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

So I want to plot a confusion matrix, this is my code

```
class ConfusionPlot():
        def __init__(self, cm):
            self.cm = cm
        def printPlot():
            dx= plt.subplot()
            sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='g', ax=dx)  
            # labels, title and ticks
            dx.set_xlabel('Predicted labels');
            dx.set_ylabel('True labels');
            dx.set_title('Confusion Matrix');
            dx.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['Died', 'Survived']);
            dx.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['Died', 'Survived'])
```

and the method call

```
cm3=confusion_matrix(y_train,pred_train2)
cplot3 = ConfusionPlot(cm3)
cplot3.printPlot(cm3)
```

The error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [360], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 cplot3.printPlot(cm3)

TypeError: printPlot() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

When it is hardcoded it works well, just like this

```
cmTest =confusion_matrix(y_test,X_test_prediction)
bx= plt.subplot()
sns.heatmap(cmTest, annot=True, fmt='g', ax=bx) 
# labels, title and ticks
bx.set_xlabel('Predicted labels');
bx.set_ylabel('True labels');
bx.set_title('Confusion Matrix');
bx.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['Died', 'Survived']);
bx.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['Died', 'Survived'])
```

How can I use this code but inside a class?

Answer (score 0):

Your function in the class doesn't take any arguments, so when you call it you don't need to give it cm3. This is the first argument it thinks it has.

```
cm3=confusion_matrix(y_train,pred_train2)
cplot3 = ConfusionPlot(cm3)
cplot3.printPlot()
```

The second issue is that you don't have self in the function. So you need to add self which is the other argument it it trying to pass in the error code.

```
class ConfusionPlot():
        def __init__(self, cm):
            self.cm = cm
        def printPlot(self):
            dx= plt.subplot()
            sns.heatmap(self.cm, annot=True, fmt='g', ax=dx)  
            # labels, title and ticks
            dx.set_xlabel('Predicted labels');
            dx.set_ylabel('True labels');
            dx.set_title('Confusion Matrix');
            dx.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['Died', 'Survived']);
            dx.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['Died', 'Survived'])
```